# Access: hide nulls fields on a report

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to show a report on MS-ACCESS.
But I need to hide null fields.

[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwg39.png)

If the textbox "actividad" is null then the checkbox hides

I tried this code but does not work

```
Private Sub Detalle_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
  MsgBox "qqddqw"
If IsNull(Me.actividad) Or Me.actividad = "" Then
    Me.realizado.Visible = False
Else
    Me.realizado.Visible = True    
End If

End Sub
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This looks like it should work, Detail_Format is the correct event to use. Try adding `Debug.Print "Visible = False (resp. True)"` to both branches of the If statement to see if they actually run. Ctrl+g shows the output.

Comment: And try using `If Nz(Me.actividad) = "" Then` instead.